# Subtract datetime objects to get numerical result in milliseconds (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

Trying to find the **elapsed time** from two strings which hold a timestamp and are in the format `hh:mm:ss.mss`. Basically, I want to subtract two `datetime` objects and get a numerical result in **milliseconds**.

Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime

elapsed_time = 0
s = '13:46:34.550'
e = '13:46:36.750'

# only interested on the time part, not the date
start_time = datetime.strptime(s, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
end_time   = datetime.strptime(e, '%H:%M:%S.%f')

#elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
#elapsed_time = (end_time - start_time).microsecond
```

For both `elapsed_time` calculations I get a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'`.

It should print `00:00:02.250` or (ideally) `2200`.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just a small quibble, the difference between thetwo times would be `00:00:02.200` or ideally, `2200`

Comment: @DamienPaul Good catch, corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following worked for me (using Python 3.5.2):

```
from datetime import datetime

elapsed_time = 0
s = '13:46:34.550'
e = '13:46:36.750'

# only interested on the time part, not the date
start_time = datetime.strptime(s, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
end_time = datetime.strptime(e, '%H:%M:%S.%f')

diff = end_time - start_time
elapsed_time = int((diff.seconds * 1000) + (diff.microseconds / 1000))
```

The output I got was `2200` which is the time difference in milliseconds between `s` and `e`

Some references:

[Python: Difference between two datetimes in milliseconds](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2015/07/28/python-difference-between-two-datetimes-in-milliseconds/) (Mark Needham's blog)

[Python docs about datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html)

A bit of explanation from the docs (linked immediately above):

In section [8.1.4 `datetime` Objects](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects), it states that for the operation:

```
timedelta = datetime1 - datetime2
```

(which corresponds to the 2nd last line of code in this answer):

> Subtraction of a `datetime` from a `datetime` is defined only if both operands are naive, or if both are aware. If one is aware and the other is naive, [`TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) is raised.

Also:

> Changed in version 3.3: Equality comparisons between naive and aware `datetime` instances don’t raise `TypeError`